# Sequences and $\mathbb{C}$-Vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Lets $x$ and $y$ nonzero complex numbers. Define $V= \{ (a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \in \mathbb{C}^{\mathbb{N}},  \forall n \in  \mathbb{N}: a_{n+2} = x a_{n+1} + ya_n  \}$. Show that $V$ is $\mathbb{C}-$vector space with $DimV = 2$ over $\mathbb{C}$.

It's obvious that $V$ is a vector space, because it is subspace of sequences space, but I don't know how to show that $DimV_{\mathbb{C}}=2$, maybe I can do an isomorphism $\phi:V \to \mathbb{C}^2$, can you give me a tip??

Comment: Send the sequence to a_0 and a_1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $a_0$ and $a_1$ you have a unique vector in $V$, as you said an isomorphism $\phi:V\to\mathbb{C}^2$ would work. let $\phi((a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}) = (a_0, a_1)$, it's easy to show this is an isomorphism.

Comment: but this is constant... it is not injective, for instace..

Comment: this is not constant, for any vector this returns only first and second numbers of vector, for example for vector $(0,1,x,x^2y,...)$ it returns $(0,1)$, for vector $(1,0,y,xy,...)$ it returns $(1,0)$.

Comment: ok, I got it, thanks.